# Compilation error when restricting template parameters of derived class with std::enable_if

Tags: c++, templates

This compiles:

```
template<typename T, class T2, class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T>::type>
 class ENABLE{
 public:
     T a;
     ENABLE(T b): a(b) {};
 };

template<typename T, class T2>
 class ENABLE_CHILD : public ENABLE<T, T2> {
 public:
    ENABLE_CHILD(T x): ENABLE<T, T>(x) {};
    bool FOO(auto a);
 };

template<typename T, class T2>
 bool ENABLE_CHILD<T, T2>::FOO(auto a) { return(1); };
```

But this does not:

```
template<typename T, class T2, class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T>::type>
 class ENABLE{
 public:
     T a;
     ENABLE(T b): a(b) {};
 };

template<typename T, class T2, class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T>::type>
 class ENABLE_CHILD : public ENABLE<T, T2> {
 public:
    ENABLE_CHILD(T x): ENABLE<T, T>(x) {};
    bool FOO(auto a);
 };

template<typename T, class T2>
 bool ENABLE_CHILD<T, T2>::FOO(auto a) { return(1); };
```

Error messages:

1. error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class ENABLE_CHILD<T, T2>'
2. note: declaration of 'class ENABLE_CHILD<T, T2> (and clicking this brings me to the declaration statement)

So my compiler thinks the class is incomplete. Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a different error when pasting this code into godbolt.org. You need to include the third template parameter on your member function definition as well: https://godbolt.org/z/kxpvQt

```
template<typename T, class T2, class Enable>
bool ENABLE_CHILD<T, T2, Enable>::FOO(auto a) { return(1); };
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you had something else in mind should T not be an arithmetic type, but I replaced the enable_ifs with static_asserts and the code compiles fine.
https://godbolt.org/z/y4f6wa

```
#include <type_traits>
template<typename T, class T2>
 class ENABLE{
      static_assert(std::is_arithmetic<T>::value);
 public:
     T a;
     ENABLE(T b): a(b) {};
 };

template<typename T, class T2>
 class ENABLE_CHILD : public ENABLE<T, T2> {
     static_assert(std::is_arithmetic<T>::value);
 public:
    ENABLE_CHILD(T x): ENABLE<T, T>(x) {};
    bool FOO(auto a);
 };

template<typename T, class T2>
 bool ENABLE_CHILD<T, T2>::FOO(auto a) { return(1); };

 int main(){
     ENABLE_CHILD<int,int> theEC(42);
     
 }
```